# Page Layout with Code Blocks

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing-page

I'm getting the following error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks

I just want to show/hide controls based on page values. How do I do that?

My current code:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">|
<SharePointWebControls:LookupField runat="server" id="lfITAlertType" FieldName="ITAlertType"/>
<%
  if (SPContext.Current.ListItem["ITAlertType"] == "BOB") {
  }
%>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I switched to this approach - placing the code in a script tag in the header:

```
    <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
        <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
        <script runat="server" type="text/c#">
            public void Page_Load()
            {       
                var itAlertType = SPContext.Current.ListItem["ITAlertType"];        
                string sITAlertType = new SPFieldLookupValue(itAlertType.ToString()).LookupValue;
                lblTest.Text = sITAlertType;
            }
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
        <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel ID="EditModePanel2" runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel title-edit">
            <SharePointWebControls:LookupField runat="server" id="ddcfTest" FieldName="ITAlertType" />
        </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblTest" text="BOB" />
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: I've updated this to show that you should use `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead` for the code block otherwise you might get issues stuffing stuff into the Title tag.